# Problems using jitpack.io with Android Gradle

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin

I'm currently trying to add dependencies with `jitpack`. I've followed the basic instructions:

```
repositories {
        maven {
        url "https:jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
}
```

But I'm still getting the following error:

What went wrong:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
    Could not find com.github.jitpack:maven-simple:4f1c2c9033.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https:/#/jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/jitpack/maven-simple/4f1c2c9033/maven-simple-4f1c2c9033.pom
         https:/#/jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/jitpack/maven-simple/4f1c2c9033/maven-simple-4f1c2c9033.jar
         https:/#/jitpack.io/com/github/jitpack/maven-simple/4f1c2c9033/maven-simple-4f1c2c9033.pom
         https:/#/jitpack.io/com/github/jitpack/maven-simple/4f1c2c9033/maven-simple-4f1c2c9033.jar
         https:/#/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/jitpack/maven-simple/4f1c2c9033/maven-simple-4f1c2c9033.pom
         https:/#/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/jitpack/maven-simple/4f1c2c9033/maven-simple-4f1c2c9033.jar
         file:/C:/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/jitpack/maven-simple/4f1c2c9033/maven-simple-4f1c2c9033.pom
         file:/C:/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/jitpack/maven-simple/4f1c2c9033/maven-simple-4f1c2c9033.jar
         file:/C:/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/jitpack/maven-simple/4f1c2c9033/maven-simple-4f1c2c9033.pom
         file:/C:/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/jitpack/maven-simple/4f1c2c9033/maven-simple-4f1c2c9033.jar
     Required by:
         Plate:app:unspecified
```

Comment: That project (maven-simple) has a release with 0.1 version. Does that work?

Answer (score 4):

Your jitpack url looks wrong.

It's:

`url "https:jitpack.io"`

but in my opinion it should be:

`url "https://jitpack.io"`.